# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3-(\tan(x))^3}{x^5}$ without applying L'Hospital 5 times?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

As the title says, how would one determine the value of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3-(\tan(x))^3}{x^5}$ without maddeningly applying L'Hospital 5 times? I tried to do this on paper, and it took me a whole page and have yet to differentiate one more time.

Is there any shortcut that could help in this case? If it is relevant, the original problem is calculating $f'(0)$, where $f(x) = (x^3-(\tan(x))^3)^\frac{1}{5}$. I began by using the definition of the derivative $f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x^3-(\tan(x))^3)^\frac{1}{5}}{x-0}$ and using the continuity of radicals I only need to calculate what's inside the radical after getting the denominators inside it, which leads me to that infernal limit. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It’s immediate if you know the Taylor polynomial of $\tan x$ of degree $3$. Indeed, Taylor polynomials are the only sane way to do such problems.

Comment: First compute the limits of $\frac{\tan x}x$ and $\frac{\tan x -x}{x^3}.$ Then derive your limit. Or expand the power series for $\tan x.$

Comment: Use the substitution $t=(\tan x) /x$ so that $t\to 1$ and expression under limit is $\frac{1-t^3}{x^2}=-\frac{t^3-1}{t-1}\cdot\frac{t-1}{x^2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{\tan x}{x}\to 1,$ and, factoring the difference of cubes

$$\frac{x^3-\tan^3 x}{x^5}=\frac{x-\tan x}{x^3}\cdot \frac{x^2+x\tan x+\tan^2 x}{x^2}$$

Now:

$$\frac{x^2+x\tan x+\tan^2x}{x^2}=1+\frac{\tan x}x+\frac{\tan^2x}{x^2}\to 3.$$

So you only need to find:

$$3\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\tan x}{x^3}$$

It turns out you only need to apply L'Hopital once here, because you get:

$$\frac{1-\sec^2x}{3x^2}=\frac{-\tan^2x}{3x^2}=-\frac13\frac{\tan^2x}{x^2}\to -\frac13.$$

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series of the tangent function centered at $0$ begins with $x+\frac{x^3}3$ and the coefficient of $x^4$ is $0$. Therefore, the terms of the Taylor series of $\tan^3$ centered at $0$ up to degree $5$ can be obtained computing $\left(x+\frac{x^3}3\right)^3$ and taking only those terms whose degree is not greater than $5$; that will give you $x^3+x^5$. So,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3-\tan^3(x)}{x^5}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3-\left(x^3+x^5\right)}{x^5}=-1.$$